# Basic create component test failing with MoJs

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular6

I have a component that is using the animation library Mojs. The create component test that comes out of the box with the spec.ts file is failing because of MoJs elements. I am not sure how to provide this library in the spec.ts file so that at the least this test for the component successfully creating passes.

The error I am getting is: *'Cannot read property 'CustomShape' of undefined'*

the implementation of this CustomShape looks like:

```
    class paperOutlineTopCorner3 extends mojs.CustomShape {
     getShape () { return '<path d="123XYZ"/>'; }
    }
```

my current spec.ts file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CallbackComponent } from './callback.component';
import { requiredTestModules } from '../testing/import.helpers';

describe('CallbackComponent', () => {
 let component: CallbackComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<CallbackComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ CallbackComponent ],
  imports: [requiredTestModules]
})
.compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CallbackComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

any help/suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll have to have your mojs object defined.
Hopefully there is a library you can install into your node_modules folder?
After you have the mojs definitions in the node_modules folder you can import it into the file and as long as mojs.CustomShape is defined in that import you should be good to go.

you might be able to do something like

```
npm install mojs
```

and then to import it, you can try a couple of different things:

i'd try require:

```
const mojs = require('mojs');
```

or import:

```
import * as mojs from 'mojs';
```

it's even easier if the mojs library has been 'typed' already.

also can you build correctly?  but only get the error when testing?  that's usually an indication that something from your .module file needs to be copied into the .spec file.

hope that helps

Comment: MAN! my problem was the import line. I had import mojs from 'mo-js';  Thanks for the much needed help

Comment: glad to help! if you dont mind, i think you might have to click the bounty button under the votes, the points may just go away if not

Comment: Sorry about that. Enjoy the bounty while I enjoy my sanity coming back.